# Autofill a cell data based on another cell in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, autofill

Is there a way to auto fill a cell in an excel sheet based on a data entry in another cell? Here is what I want to do: Suppose I have two columns in my sheet `(A,B)`. I want the column `B` to show data based on a data range in the column `A`, for example if the value entered is between 0 and 20 I want to the column `B` to show `Bad`, and if the value entered is between 21 and 60 I want `B` to show `OK` etc. How can I do that?

I am using Excel 2013. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(A1<20;"Bad";IF(AND(20<A1;A1<60);"Ok"))
```

Place this formula in cell B1, simply copy and paste on other cells in column B to implement this formula.